# User needs to press enter twice for loop to be initialized

Tags: java, do-while

I finished a beginner's game program and it works fine, except it's a bit slow when it prompts the user to play again. It is a do...while loop that goes around the entire main method. I want to make it so that the user only needs to type "1" and press enter ONCE rather than twice for the game to replay.

How can I fix this? Also, I'm not sure which part of my program I need to show (if needed), so if you need that, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
if (correctc == 3 && correctp == 3){
    System.out.println("\nUser wins! Colour was " + colchoice);
    System.out.println("Press 1 to play again with a new combo.");
    pagain = myInput.readLine(); // game starts with new combo or ends
}

// User tries guessing again
else{
    System.out.println("\nEnter 1 to guess again.");
    loop = myInput.readLine();
}

}while("1".equals(loop)); // user continues guessing the same combo
}while("1".equals(pagain)); // new game with new combo
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is readLine() waits for line to be terminated by "\n" (an enter in this case). You use it twice:

```
pagain = myInput.readLine();
```

and then

```
loop = myInput.readLine();
```

Isn't "pagain" supposed to be doin what your "loop" is doing? I beileve it is possible to use only one variable to steer both of these loops. For example, you ask to type in "1" to loop again the same set and type in "2" to try with a new set. Then you can get rid of the "loop" variable. It will go out of the inner do-while when it checks that you typed in "2".